# Are lucene indexes created on database views?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We are using elastic search provided OOB by PRPC tool. But the questions I have are generic.

Are lucene indexes are created on database views?
How lucene indexes can be leveraged when I had to join multiple tables? If yes, how lucene indexes work while joining tables?

Comment: What is OOB by PRPC?

Comment: out of the box by pega rule process commander. PRPC is a BPM tool.